# Banach space isometric to its dual

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a real or complex Banach space linearly isometric to its Banach dual $X^\star$. Is it true that $X$ is reflexive?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560293/if-a-banach-space-x-is-isometric-to-its-first-dual-x-must-x-be-reflexiv

Comment: Why is this $X$ isometric to its dual?

Comment: [deleted earlier comment which had a silly oversight]